# Div elements move when viewed in mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have an issue when viewing a site on mobile, where the fly out menu icon and main icon go missing off the screen. This may be due to incorrect input of bootstrap code but it's proving hard to fix.

[Mobile site view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0os2O.png)

[Bootstrap code for icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2TKZ.png)

```
        <div class="container-fluid">


            <!-- change the image in style.css to the class header .container-fluid [approximately row 50] -->
            <div class="container">
   <header id="home">
            <!-- change the image in style.css to the class header .container-fluid [approximately row 50] -->
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"></div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-10 col-xs-2 text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail logo"><img src="images/MJW Star3.png" alt="" class="img5"></a></span>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-8 col-xs-2 text-center">
                        <div class="menu-btn"><span class="hamburger">&#9776;</span>


        </div>
```

Comment: I click on your pictures, but I'm still a little confused as to what elements you're specifically having trouble with. Can you post a Minimal Verifiable Example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I was having trouble pasting the code but the html is above